# My system cannot run any servlet how do i fix this?

Tags: java, html, servlets, resources, compilation

My system has tomcat seven and all the filles are under webapp. The file structure is

webapps/
    WelcomeForm/
       web/
          WelcomeForm.html
                   WEB-INF/
                       web.xml
                          lib/
                          classes/
                               hello/
                                 HelloWorldServlet.java
                                 HelloWorldServlet.class

The web folder holds WelcomeForm.html. WEB-INF holds the web.xml. lib holds servlet-api.jar and classes holds HelloWorldServlet.java. the hmtl file runs fine but i cannot run the java file as it returns the message:

HTTP Status 404 - /hello

type Status report

message /hello

description The requested resource (/hello) is not available.

The code for the files is below:

WelcomeForm.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome Form</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
           <form method="POST" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/hello">
        <font size="10" color="red">Hello World!</font><BR>

     Type your first name and click submit button <input TYPE=TEXT NAME="username" SIZE=20>
            <P><input type="submit" value="Submit">


       </form> 

    </body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>hello.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

HelloWorldServlet.java

```
package hello;

import java.io.IOException; 
import javax.servlet.ServletException; 
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; 
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
response.setContentType("text/html");

      doPost(request,response);
      }

   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name = request.getParameter("username");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write("Your Name is :" );
    out.print(name);

  }    
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is virtual directory path

Comment: C:\Users\Matthew\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.26-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\webapps\labs\lab10\WelcomeForm

Comment: what URL of servlet you give?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/labs/lab10/WelcomeForm/web/WelcomeForm.html

Comment: Try this and tell me if it works localhost:8080/web/WelcomeForm.html

Comment: it give the error the resource is not available

Comment: `HelloWorldt` can't be right, right?

Comment: sorry that was a typo and it didnt change anything after i corrected it

Comment: everything is in the right place but it still does not work

Answer (score 1):

Your tree is not correct. A webapp's folder (or war) must be placed in Tomcat's webapps folder.

Directly under the webapp's root folder (`Welcome form` in your case, but you should really avoid spaces in folder names, because they must be encoded in URLs and make things harder tha necessary), there must be a folder named `WEB-INF`.

The servlet-api.jar must not be in the WEB-INF/lib folder. Tomcat obviously already has this jar in its classpath.

If the name of the webapp's folder is `Welcome form`, why do you use the URL `/labs/lab10/WelcomeForm/`. The URL should be `/Welcome form/...`

In the web.xml file, the `<servlet-class>` element must be the fully qualified name of the class of the servlet. So if the class is named HelloWorldServlet and is in the package com.foo.bar, the element must contain `com.foo.bar.HelloWorldServlet`.

And of course, the `<servlet-mapping>` element is used to map a given servlet to a URL (or a set of URLs). You should thus use this URL to invoke your servlet: http://hostname/Welcome form/HelloWorldServlet.

In short, you have everything wrong. You should re-read your book or tutorial about servlets and web applications. Here's one for you: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html

Comment: The webapps folder is the one in the tomcat directory and using the servlet-mapping url did not work it gives the same error as before

Comment: the space in WelcomeForm was a typo and there is no package

Comment: NEVER put a class in the default package. And fix all the other errors.

Comment: then how do i change the package? I have moved the WEB-INF folder to under the WelcomeForm folder

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html. Learn Java basics before developing webapps.

Comment: Search on hosting in tomcat server you have may be you get help from some book.

Comment: i changed the package and altered the web.xml it still does not work

Comment: Take some time. Read the tutorial I gave you or find some other one which explains how to implement and deploy a servlet in tomcat step by step. Follow it from the beginning to the end. Without seeing the exact structure of your deployed webapp, the source code of the class and of web.xml, and the URL you use to invoke your servlet, I can't tell where your error is.

Comment: i cant compile the files the command prompt doesnt recognise the imports what do i do?